# Inserir dados em uma text box em tempo real com Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, thread, timer

Estou usando `timer` da seguinte forma:

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Interval = 1000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

No método `OnTimedEvent` faço o seguinte:

```
var auditoria = auditoriaBll.Retorna_Auditoria();

foreach (var item in auditoria)
{
    //menu e sub menu (categorias)
    if (item.Tabela.Equals("menus")) 
    {
        txtRelatorio.Text = andamento;
    }
}
```

O seguinte erro acontece:

> Operação entre threads inválida: controle 'txtRelatorio' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente, você só pode acessar elementos criados numa *thread* dentro desta mesma *thread*. Pra resolver, você precisa usar o método [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var auditoria = auditoriaBll.Retorna_Auditoria();

foreach (var item in auditoria)
{
    //menu e sub menu (categorias)
    if (item.Tabela.Equals("menus")) 
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => txtRelatorio.Text = andamento));
    }
}
```

Comment: esse método Invoke é um delegate type? se for, tenho que criar?

Comment: Método `Invoke` é da classe `Control` (veja na documentação, eu linkei na resposta). O método recebe um `delegate`, mas eu fiz com uma expressão lambda porque fica bem mais simples.

Comment: ;Aparece o seguinte erro: Severity Code Description Project 
Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Já editei a resposta... Aliás, eu até ia melhorar pra te dar umas dicas, mas sua pergunta é duplicada.